# Error message "Required field is not provided" in Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

```
public ResponseEntity<Document> fetchRep(
    @Parameter(name = "fromDate", description = "${AbcController.fromDate.ApiParam.value}",
      required = true,
      example = "2023-01-11", schema = @Schema(type = "String"),
      allowEmptyValue = false) @RequestHeader(value = "fromDate", required = true) String fromDate,
    @Parameter(name = "toDate", description = "${AbcController.toDate.ApiParam.value}",
      required = true,
      example = "2023-01-11",
      schema = @Schema(type = "String"), allowEmptyValue = false) @RequestHeader(value = "toDate", required = true) String toDate
```

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQes5.png)

yaml doc -

```
AbcController:
 fromDate:
   ApiParam:
    value: 'Holds the date from which the report data is generated. [yyyy-mm-dd]'
 toDate:
   ApiParam:
    value: 'Holds the date till which the report data is generated [yyyy-mm-dd]'
```

Can you please tell me why i am getting this validation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```java
@Schema(type = "String")
```

to

```java
@Schema(type = "string")
```

Note lowercase "s" in "string".